# compose sms task in windows phone 7 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

**I am trying to do a composeSMS task in windows phone 7.
And i have a array of data retrieve from isolated storage.
How can i make it loop to get all the data into one message.
Below is my code but it only get the lastest data.**

```
private void sendSmsBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //For sorted time
        StreamReader readFileTime = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fullFolderName + "\\time.Schedule", FileMode.Open, myStore));

        //For time
        StreamReader readFileTime1 = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fullFolderName + "\\time1.Schedule", FileMode.Open, myStore));

        //For title
        StreamReader readFileTitle = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fullFolderName + "\\title.Schedule", FileMode.Open, myStore));

        //For category
        StreamReader readFileCategory = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fullFolderName + "\\category.Schedule", FileMode.Open, myStore));


        //Sorted time list
        String timeText = readFileTime.ReadLine();
        timeSplit = timeText.Split(new char[] { '^' });
            Array.Sort(timeSplit, delegate(string first, string second)
        {
            return DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(first), Convert.ToDateTime(second));
        });


        String timeText1 = readFileTime1.ReadLine();

        timeSplit1 = timeText1.Split(new char[] { '^' });
        //Array.Sort(timeSplit1);

        String titleText = readFileTitle.ReadLine();
        titleSplit = titleText.Split(new char[] { '^' });
        Array.Sort(titleSplit);

        String categoryText = readFileCategory.ReadLine();
        categorySplit = categoryText.Split(new char[] { '^' });
        Array.Sort(categorySplit);
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
    }



    SmsComposeTask composeSMS = new SmsComposeTask();

        for (int i = 0; i < timeSplit.Length; i++)
        {
            timeList = timeSplit[i];
            titleList = titleSplit[i];
            categoryList = categorySplit[i];


            composeSMS.Body = "Below is my schedule: \n" +
                              "Date: " + timeList + "\n" +
                              "Time: " + titleList + "\n" +
                              "End time: " + categoryList + "\n";

        }
        composeSMS.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** You are constantly setting the message body in the loop instead of appending data to it. For it to work, you need to have:

```
composeSMS.Body += "Below is my schedule: \n" +
                 "Date: " + timeList + "\n" +
                 "Time: " + titleList + "\n" +
                 "End time: " + categoryList + "\n";
```

---

Now, let me point out that your code is not optimized and can generally be shortened. For example, look at this:

```
private void sendSmsBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader reader;
        string[] timeSplit;
        string[] timeSplit1;
        string[] titleSplit;
        string placeholder;
        string[] categorySplit;

        //For sorted time
        using (reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fullFolderName + "\\time.Schedule", FileMode.Open, myStore))
        {
            placeholder = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        timeSplit = placeholder.Split(new char[] { '^' });
        Array.Sort(timeSplit, delegate(string first, string second)
        {
           return DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(first), Convert.ToDateTime(second)); 
        }); 

        using (reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fullFolderName + "\\time1.Schedule", FileMode.Open, myStore))
        {
            placeholder = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        timeSplit1 = placeholder.Split(new char[] { '^' });
        Array.Sort(titleSplit1);

        using (reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fullFolderName + "\\title.Schedule", FileMode.Open, myStore)))
        {
            placeholder = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        titleSplit = placeholder.Split(new char[] { '^' });
        Array.Sort(titleSplit);

        using(reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fullFolderName + "\\category.Schedule", FileMode.Open, myStore)))
        {
            placeholder = readFileCategory.ReadLine();
        }

        categorySplit = placeholder.Split(new char[] { '^' });
        Array.Sort(categorySplit);
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    var composeSMS = new SmsComposeTask();
    var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    sBuilder.AppendLine("Below is my schedule:");

    for (int i = 0; i < timeSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.AppendLine("Date: " + timeSplit[i]);
        sBuilder.AppendLine("Time: " + titleSplit[i]);
        sBuilder.AppendLine("End time: " + categorySplit[i]);
    }

    composeSMS.Body = sBuilder.ToString();
    composeSMS.Show();
}
```

> **NOTE:** I edited your code in Notepad without having access to a
>   compiler. Some modifications might be needed.

Here are some major differences from what you have.

- I am re-using the same **reader** (instance of StreamReader) over and over instead of creating new instances for every single file.
- Notice the **using** statement used along the lines where the reader is used. Also notice curly braces - that way, the **reader** instance will be properly disposed once I am done working with it (reading a file).
- You only need one instance of a **placeholder** string, since all composite line strings are never used anywhere. That **placeholder** string is reset with every read.
- I am using a **StringBuilder** to build the body and only when it's ready, I am setting the **Body** property.
- No need for intermediary variables inside the loop.

Last but not least - a very important advice. You **need to** refactor the way you are storing data. Reading four files in this case to build a single entity is wrong and resource-consuming. Consider using a single well-structured format (e.g. XML or JSON) to store the data in a single file. Even better, consider using a database (starting SDK v.7.1 there is support for SQL CE).